# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called when table view is not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

There are a lot of questions and answers on this topic but I could not find one for this situation.

The app has been in production for about 3 years so I'm confident that the table view in question and all the other table views are already wired up correctly. I'm adding a new feature and I'm encountering something I didn't expect.

Here's the situation:

- The user taps tab 1 displaying a list of items in a table view.
- The user taps tab 2 and imports more items.
- A notification is fired off.
- The observer on the view controller on tab 1 receives the notification and invokes its selector.
- The selector updates the model and calls `reloadData:`.
- `numberOfRowsInSection:` gets called and returns the correct number of rows.

Up to this point everything is working exactly like I'd expect. But that's where it stops. After `numberOfRowsInSection:` there is nothing else. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called.

Obviously, the table view I'm reloading is not visible. It's on another tab.

Is this behaviour is an optimization where `reloadData` is simply not executed because the table isn't visible? Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: please show some relevant code, where did you call reloadData

Comment: @AhmedDaou Thanks for offering to look but I'm confident that posting code won't add any value in this case. As I mentioned in the comment below the answer is right in the docs: `For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes perfect sense to me, except the part where your table view calls numberOfRowsInSection:. I would not expect that when the VC is not visible.

If the table view is not in the current view hierarchy it won't draw.

Comment: I guess it's right there in the docs for `reloadData:` `For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible.` I've always known that but I've only thought about it in terms of a table view that's visible. If the model has a thousand items it only redraws the 10 that are visible. That has always made perfect sense. Now that I reread it in the light of this situation it also makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As Duncan points out a VC will not reload the tableView unless it is in the current view hierarchy. I've recently been working on an app which uses a lot of KVO for updating tableViews, and the best solution I could come up with was simply to mark the view as dirty by having a property BOOL needsRedraw on the viewController in question. Then when viewWillAppear: is called in that viewController you should be able to reload the tableview

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing. In the selector invoked by the notification i set the flag, then in `viewWillAppear:` I check it. If it's set I clear it, update the model, and call `reloadData:`. It works just fine.